glob star pattern matching man pages

3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching
Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special
pattern characters described below, matches itself. The NUL character
may not occur in a pattern. A backslash escapes the following
character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching. The
special pattern characters must be quoted if they are to be matched
literally.
The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
* Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a filename expansion
context, two adjacent ‘*’s used as a single pattern will match all
files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by
a ‘/’, two adjacent ‘*’s will match only directories and
subdirectories.

What is a null character?
What is a null string? What’s the difference between a null character?
What this means exactly?

A backslash escapes the following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching.
...
When the globstar shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a filename expansion context, two adjacent ‘*’s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a ‘/’, two adjacent ‘*’s will match only directories and subdirectories.

Could you give some examples ?

For "examples", probably the best bet is to play with ls [search-string] after cd-ing into a directory with a wide range of filenames. Include asterisks and backslashes in the search string, to see what matches. Learn by doing is usually better than being told.

The NUL character is a specific one-byte ASCII character often represented as \0 or Hex 0x00. It is the C string terminator and is not permitted in filenames etc. The "null string" here means that the asterisk character matches a string of characters of any length, including matching an empty string containing no characters at all.

It doesn’t search abNUL character is not permitted in file names ? Correct? A backslash escapes the following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching. What is this backslash escapes following one character?

The NUL character may not occur in a pattern. It means is not permitted in filenames ?

@ChrisDavies  Apparently not, as that question was asked by the same person 3 months ago.

@user599592  Some characters are "invisible": newline, tab, escape -- in fact, the first 32 characters shown by man ascii, and the last one DEL. Also backslash itself. Many of those can be typed in some languages in visible forms, like \n \t \r \0. These forms are also shown in man ascii. The two characters \0 are converted to the single byte NUL internally.

@Paul_Pedant I can't see what's significantly different between the two questions

@ChrisDavies  Me neither. I wonder if he didn't see the first answer, didn't understand it, or didn't remember it. Confusing ascii NUL, \0, "0", and an empty substring matching * should not be this hard.
